# Add key pair to EC2 instance for AWS EKS Kubernetes Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I used the Terraform module [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest) to create an AWS EKS kubernetes cluster.

How can i add a key pair to the EC2 instance that'll be used for the worker & master nodes?

The reason for this is to be able to SSH into the node directly using the key pair.
If i don't use this approach of adding a key pair, how else can i SSH into the node itself from my local machine?

What i thought of using is: `cluster_ca_certificate` but I'm not sure if this will work, or how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this block to your terraform code:

```
  worker_groups_launch_template = [
    {
      name                  = "on-demand"
      key_name              = "key-name-must-exist"
      instance_type         = "t3a.xlarge"
      asg_min_size          = 1
      asg_desired_capacity  = 1
      asg_max_size          = 5
      autoscaling_enabled   = true
      asg_force_delete      = true
      enable_monitoring     = false
      enabled_metrics       = ["GroupMinSize", "GroupMaxSize", "GroupDesiredCapacity"]
      kubelet_extra_args    = ""
      additional_userdata   = ""
      suspended_processes   = ["AZRebalance"]
      subnets               = private_subnets
      tags = [
        {
          "key"                 = "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled"
          "propagate_at_launch" = "false"
          "value"               = "true"
        },
        {
          "key"                 = "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/clustername"
          "propagate_at_launch" = "false"
          "value"               = "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Remember to change the key_name to match with your ssh key and edit the SG of nodes so that it can receive traffic directly from your local machine